# System.data, ServiceModel.XmlSerializerFormatAttribute in windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7

I need to consume the WCF from my windows phone app and it creates the proxy with the need of using System.Data and Servicemodel.XmlSerializerFormatAttribute.

I can't see a way to add this namespace into this windows phone app? please help?

Comment: Does the service require the namespaces or the application?

Comment: Dennis - sorry not sure what question is? but let me re-phrase my questions. My windows phone app is missing : System.Runtime.Serialization.IExtensibleDataObject, System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject, and System.Data. The app is saying the type/namaspace does not exist.

Comment: Are you consuming the WCF service by adding it as a service reference?

Comment: Bare in mind that XML ~4 times bigger than Json (Internet connection is still expensive for phones). If you can use Json.Net. More info: http://blogs.claritycon.com/blogs/kevin_marshall/archive/2010/11/03/wp7-serialization-comparison.aspx

Comment: I have an existing WCF services which currently consumed by my WPF app. Now I'm building WP7, trying not to create a new service but using the existing WCF services. Can you please advise which the best way would be? or it is a dead-end, meaning I need to create a brand new service?

Comment: Simply add a service reference.

Comment: the existing wcf service is using wsHttpBinding and i believe WP7 only supports webHttpBinding? I'm having an error "NokeyFoundException" error

Answer (score 1):

IExtensibleDataObject and ExtensionDataObject are not supported in Silverlight (therefore, not supported in a Windows Phone 7 Silverlight-based application).

You will have no problem using XmlSerializerFormatAttribute  (as per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.xmlserializerformatattribute(v=VS.95).aspx)), but your app should have a way around System.Data, since it is not supported.

In your case, what you should do is directly pass a service reference by adding it in your project.

[image]

Make sure you use the correct WCF service URL and it should work right away:

[image]

The namespace you are specifying will be the one you will use in the code-behind to access the service methods.

Comment: How do I consume WCF service then if System.Data not supported?

Comment: the existing wcf service is using wsHttpBinding and i believe WP7 only supports webHttpBinding? I'm having an error "NokeyFoundException" error

Comment: That would be correct - to use the WCF service on WP7 you have to implement webHttpBinding.

Answer (score -1):

Probably, in your project, first you need to add reference to the System.Data and System.ServiceModel.

Comment: Some libraries are not supported on WP7 because of specific platform restrictions. For example, System.Data is not supported.